# JPA query a collection using between clause

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, criteria

My entity has a collection of another entity on which I need to do a `BETWEEN` criteria.
I do not want to use the native query.
I am trying to achieve this using the criteria API.

Below is a short snippet of my entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ref_dates")
public class Dates{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
    name="ref_dates_prg",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="DATE_PRG_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="DATE_ID")
 )    
 private Set<DateInfo> dates;
```

}

It has several other properties, geter/setters, etc which I have not mentioned here.
I need to do a query on this `Set` for the id's in `DateInfo` object using `between` clause.
I tried using `Expression<Set<DateInfo>>` but haven't reached anywhere.
Thanks for all the help.

Here is my criteria build up.

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

final CriteriaQuery<NetPrgTimePeriod> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Dates.class);

List<Predicate> criteriaList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

final Root<Dates> root = criteriaQuery.from(Dates.class);

Join<Dates, DateInfo> dateJoin = root.join("dates", JoinType.LEFT);

Predicate runDatesRange = criteriaBuilder.between(
        dateJoin.<Integer> get("id"), startDate.getId(), endDate.getId());

criteriaList.add(runDatesRange);

Join<Dates, TimeInfo> timeJoin = root.join("times", JoinType.LEFT);

Predicate timeBlocksRange = criteriaBuilder.between(
        timeJoin.<Integer> get("id"), startTime.getId(), endTime.getId());

criteriaList.add(timeBlocksRange);

criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaList.toArray(new Predicate[0])));

TypedQuery<NetPrgTimePeriod> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

List<Dates> results = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Is this your full entity? Because as it stands, your `Set` will end up as a blob column `dates`, not as a FK mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you actually mapped your collection correctly, the main part you seem to be missing is the `Join`:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Dates> query = cb.createQuery(Dates.class);

Root<Dates> root = query.from(Dates.class);
Join<Dates, DateInfo> infos = root.join("dates", JoinType.LEFT);

query.distinct(true);
em.createQuery(query.where(cb.between(infos.<Integer>get("id"), 1, 10))).getResultList();
```

Of course you can substitute metamodel fields where I used strings (which will also obsolete the need for this ugly `<Integer>` selector - assuming your id *is* an integer).

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my original code to include more appropriate mapping. The join is already specified in the entity for the set.

Comment: @user3536652 Yeah, but I'm talking about the `Join` interface used in the query (named `infos` here). If that doesn't work for you, can you edit your post with the criteria query you tried and which doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks @Mabi, This will get me started. will update you on the result.

Comment: Didnt work as expected, it is returning more rows with additional joins. The set contains all the values instead of the filtered values (Is it supposed to filter Set?) I have added my criteria build up code.

Comment: @user3536652 I've edited my post to only include `distinct` rows. This gets rid of your first problem. As for the second: it's normal behavior for Hibernate to return all elements of the set. You need an additional result transformer or filter code in java.

Comment: Came to edit this post to mention the distinct in criteriaQuery and thats exactly what you suggested :).

Thanks.